# mediaelement.js - pause all players (iOS)

Tags: mediaelement.js

I have an array (`allPlayers`) of MediaElement audio players. There are multiple players on the page, and I call this function when a new track is started, to ensure that no two tracks play simultaneously.

```
for (i = 0; i < allPlayers.length; i++) {
    allPlayers[i].pause();
}
```

It works fine, **except not on iOS**. Why does `pause()` not work in Safari Mobile?

Comment: Hmm, updated MediaElement.js from 2.1 to 2.4 and it started working. Now `play()` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this code instead:

```
$('video,audio').mediaelementplayer().pause();
```