# MediaElement.js doesn't pause on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, jquery-mobile, mediaelement.js

I use `JQM` 1.4 and  `MediaElements` (latest)...

I use multipage template  and I want to pause the audio player every time I change the page...

I use this code...

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", function (e, ui) {
    $("audio").each(function () {
        $(this)[0].pause(); 
    });
});
```

It works fine on `Android` and `Firefox` but a problem arises in `iOS`...

The audio tag has `id="audio_element"`.

I tried different  solutions...  I have the identical problem...
[mediaelement.js - pause all players (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386432/mediaelement-js-pause-all-players-ios) (the question is old so I guess code has changed).

So I don't know other solutions...  any idea ?

Comment: Can you post the code in which you create the medialements.js player? (something like `$('video,audio').mediaelementplayer(/* Options */);`...)

Comment: $('#set').append(content).collapsibleset().find('audio').mediaelementplayer();
  $('button').attr("data-role","none");

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", function (e, ui) {
    $("audio").each(function () {
        this.player.pause(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: no I have multiple audio elements...  and your code doesnt work :(

Comment: Hmm, I'll investigate this